# Get extended spaCy morphological information

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am looking to use spaCy for my research and morphological information is important for me.

Reading [the documentation on rule-based morphology](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#rule-based-morphology), I can't figure out how I can convert the tag (e.g. NNP, VBZ) to morphological vectors (e.g. VerbForm=Fin, Mood=Ind, Tense=Pres). Is there perhaps a built-in [tag map](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#tag-map) available? Something like this (built-in) would be useful, but I can't seem to find it:

```
{
    "NNS":  {POS: NOUN, "Number": "plur"},
    "VBG":  {POS: VERB, "VerbForm": "part", "Tense": "pres", "Aspect": "prog"},
    "DT":   {POS: DET}
    ...
}
```

I found [the PoS Tagging table](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#pos-tagging), but I can't find out if this mapping is available in code or even directly in the parsed tokens?

---

I found [the tagmap for English](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/tag_map.py) on GitHub but I'm unsure how to import it. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further investigation of the [language class](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/__init__.py), I found that you can get the default tag map by using

```
> nlp = spacy.load('en')
> print(nlp.Defaults.tag_map)
{'.': {74: 96, 'PunctType': 'peri'}, ',': {74: 96, 'PunctType': 'comm'}, '-LRB-': {74: 96, 'PunctType': 'brck', 'PunctSide': 'ini'}, '-RRB-': {74: 96, 'PunctType': 'brck', 'PunctSide': 'fin'}, '``': {74: 96, 'PunctType': 'quot', 'PunctSide': 'ini'}, '""': {74: 96, 'PunctType': 'quot', 'PunctSide': 'fin'}, "''": {74: 96, 'PunctType': 'quot', 'PunctSide': 'fin'}, ':': {74: 96}, '$': {74: 98, 'Other': {'SymType': 'currency'}}, '#': {74: 98, 'Other': {'SymType': 'numbersign'}}, 'AFX': {74: 83, 'Hyph': 'yes'}, 'CC': {74: 88, 'ConjType': 'coor'}, 'CD': {74: 92, 'NumType': 'card'}, 'DT': {74: 89}, 'EX': {74: 85, 'AdvType': 'ex'}, 'FW': {74: 100, 'Foreign': 'yes'}, 'HYPH': {74: 96, 'PunctType': 'dash'}, 'IN': {74: 84}, 'JJ': {74: 83, 'Degree': 'pos'}, 'JJR': {74: 83, 'Degree': 'comp'}, 'JJS': {74: 83, 'Degree': 'sup'}, 'LS': {74: 96, 'NumType': 'ord'}, 'MD': {74: 99, 'VerbType': 'mod'}, 'NIL': {74: ''}, 'NN': {74: 91, 'Number': 'sing'}, 'NNP': {74: 95, 'NounType': 'prop', 'Number': 'sing'}, 'NNPS': {74: 95, 'NounType': 'prop', 'Number': 'plur'}, 'NNS': {74: 91, 'Number': 'plur'}, 'PDT': {74: 83, 'AdjType': 'pdt', 'PronType': 'prn'}, 'POS': {74: 93, 'Poss': 'yes'}, 'PRP': {74: 94, 'PronType': 'prs'}, 'PRP$': {74: 83, 'PronType': 'prs', 'Poss': 'yes'}, 'RB': {74: 85, 'Degree': 'pos'}, 'RBR': {74: 85, 'Degree': 'comp'}, 'RBS': {74: 85, 'Degree': 'sup'}, 'RP': {74: 93}, 'SP': {74: 102}, 'SYM': {74: 98}, 'TO': {74: 93, 'PartType': 'inf', 'VerbForm': 'inf'}, 'UH': {74: 90}, 'VB': {74: 99, 'VerbForm': 'inf'}, 'VBD': {74: 99, 'VerbForm': 'fin', 'Tense': 'past'}, 'VBG': {74: 99, 'VerbForm': 'part', 'Tense': 'pres', 'Aspect': 'prog'}, 'VBN': {74: 99, 'VerbForm': 'part', 'Tense': 'past', 'Aspect': 'perf'}, 'VBP': {74: 99, 'VerbForm': 'fin', 'Tense': 'pres'}, 'VBZ': {74: 99, 'VerbForm': 'fin', 'Tense': 'pres', 'Number': 'sing', 'Person': 3}, 'WDT': {74: 83, 'PronType': 'int|rel'}, 'WP': {74: 91, 'PronType': 'int|rel'}, 'WP$': {74: 83, 'Poss': 'yes', 'PronType': 'int|rel'}, 'WRB': {74: 85, 'PronType': 'int|rel'}, 'ADD': {74: 100}, 'NFP': {74: 96}, 'GW': {74: 100}, 'XX': {74: 100}, 'BES': {74: 99}, 'HVS': {74: 99}, '_SP': {74: 102}}
```